# The file couldn’t be opened because URL type http isn’t supported

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

Using iOS 9 I'm attempting to use `NSFileManager's` `moveItemAtURL`:

```
do {
    print(localURL) // http://localhost:3000/api/v1/activities
    print(cacheFile) // file:///Users/kyledecot/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/35C03988-D8F5-42E5-AB35-B99BE461EEAE/data/Containers/Data/Application/69593B3A-F764-4BC3-89AD-72B701BF85C8/Library/Caches/activities.json 
    try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(localURL, toURL: cacheFile)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

When catching the error I'm getting:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The file “activities” couldn’t be opened because URL type http isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=http://localhost:3000/api/v1/activities}

### Update #1

I've already added the appropriate values to my `Info.plist` to ensure that ATS is happy (see screenshot). What's odd is that I am able to download the data from my local server using HTTP (via `dataTaskWithRequest:`) but NSFileManager then complains about the same URL when trying to perform `moveItemAtURL`.

[image]

Comment: Matt's answer is correct. Since you are using `localhost` I assume you have a local setup of your API for testing. I would recommend disabling ATS [only in your Debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390228/is-it-possible-to-disable-ats-in-ios-9-just-for-debug-environment) configuration so that ATS is still applicable in the released application. Another approach would be to whitelist localhost explicitly rather than a blanket approach of disabling ATS all together.

Comment: @vcsjones I've added the required keys for (temporarily) disabling ATS but to no avail. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Well, but `localURL` is not a ` file:///` URL, so it's hard to see what on earth you expect to happen here. NSFileManager deals with _files_, not URLs in the broader sense. Your code makes no sense. Updated my answer to point that out. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two things to know here:

- In iOS 9, by default, `http://` is not supported. You must communicate securely (with `https://`). You can turn off this feature in your *Info.plist* if you have to.
- NSFileManager URLs must be paths to files on disk — that is, they must be *file* URLs. Yours is not; it's an `http://` URL. If your goal is to download a file and then copy it somewhere, use NSURLSession's download task.

Comment: I added `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads (YES)` under `NSAppTransportSecurity` but it didn't seem to help. Any ideas?