# How do I set NSAppTransportSecurity at runtime?

Tags: swift, cocoa, info.plist, nsapptransportsecurity

I already know that I can configure `NSAppTransportSecurity` in my `Info.plist` file, setting, e.g., `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to 1 to allow WKWebView to access files over http. But suppose I want to make domain-specific exceptions, but don't know what the exceptions will be until runtime. (For instance, suppose I need http access in a dev environment, but if I find I'm in production at runtime I don't want any exceptions). Is there any way to programmatically set `NSAppTransportSecurity` at runtime?

Comment: Nope, `Info.plist` is the only way to set it.

Comment: There are ways to potentially load and change values in your Info.plist file at runtime, but this will break your app's code signature.

Comment: @JAL could you point me to those ways?

Comment: @TAGraves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390228/is-it-possible-to-disable-ats-in-ios-9-just-for-debug-environment here you can see how to have different value for different environment assuming you use build configurations to manage dev/prod builds. Hope this helps.

Comment: @zhaow thanks for the response. Unfortunately this isn't quite what I was looking for, since one of our project requirements (for reasons) was to have a single build that would run in dev-mode if the device was connected to our dev network. Ultimately that requirement hasn't seemed feasible and so using different build configs is a decent alternative.