# iOS: Shipping apps using HTTPS where HTTP used in development

Tags: ios, ssl, https, app-transport-security

In production we will use a REST web service secured with SSL (HTTPS) while in development we're not using SSL (HTTP).

To allow HTTP communication we've configured our development hosts with [NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/31254874#31254874).

Is it considered acceptable to ship apps with this setting or is there a better way to do this?  We weren't sure if Apple would object to this configuration.

Comment: Similar problem discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390228/is-it-possible-to-disable-ats-in-ios-9-just-for-debug-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Roman's suggested approach and enabled ATS for debug but disabled it for all release builds.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32704702/47281