# <REACT-NATIVE> loading from prebundled file,i want that loading from port:8081 ,how can id do?

Tags: react-native

### react-native issue

project reload, at the top of screen,it show loading from prebundled file,i want that loading from port,how can i do? thanks in advance！
I tried edit the scheme from debug to release,but it seem nothing useful!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713678/react-native-using-pre-bundled-file-on-device-even-if-dev-mode/41713807 possible duplicated

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, modify the AppDelegate.m and fix jsCodeLocation to something like this

`#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.10.nip.io:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
  #else
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  #endif`

Replace `192.168.1.10.nip.io:8081` with the address of your packager.